# Some questions about css overflow and paning and zooming

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, maps

I have done a map with divs and css that you can find a test file from on http://test.rickardp.se/test.html

But i trying to get paning and zoom function on it, the best should be that it should work like Google Maps that the user can zoom with the scroll wheel on the mouse and paning with click and drag.

With that the area where the map should be showed should be smaller now i using the whole browser window.

I have search and tried some code with overflow:hidden but i have not got anything to work and the best solutions is only for images.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good starting point:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default

Try putting a draggable element inside a "viewing window" and set the "viewing window" overflow to hidden.

**UPDATE**

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/7fwYK/

**RESOURCES**

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default

Comment: thanks, only zoom function left then :-) but maybe i can figure out better becouse some math with bigger size of divs then